# A question on conformal transformation

Tags: complex-numbers, analyticity

In Blumenhagen "Introduction to conformal field theory" book page no 12 it is proved that a holomorphic function $f(z)=z+\epsilon(z)$ gives a conformal transformation. My questions are:

1. what exactly the [holomorphic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function)?
2. what is the main difference between holomorphic and anti-holomorphic?
3. Another question that can all holomorphic functions are able to give conformal transformation and is it is the only one to give such kind of transformation?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Maybe, I am a physicist and I  prefer to know how a physicist thinks about it. Sometimes what happens is that physicist and mathematician tell the same thing but in a different way. Maybe you can understand both the language but there are some people like me may not understand clearly the mathematician explanation. So please don't try to find a mistake if we know the answer tell us. We are not Forcing you to give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A physicist's answer would be that a holomorphic function is a function that depends on $z$ only, and not on $\bar{z}$.

For instance, the following expressions define holomorphic functions: 
$$ z^n \, , \sqrt{z} , \,  e^z , \, \sin z , \, \frac{az+b}{cz+d} , \, \dots $$

On the other hand, $|z| = \sqrt{z \bar{z}}$ does not define a holomorphic function.

An anto-holomorphic function is a function that depends on $\bar{z}$ only, and not on $z$.

I repeat that this is an intuitive answer. For more rigorous statements, you can refer to the linked Wikipedia article.

As for your third question, it is not very clear to me what you are asking.